# FileZilla filters: get only directory structure to local

Tags: download, filtering, ftp-client, filezilla

I'm using FileZilla FTP client. I want to get only the directory structure from server to my local computer. I try to use filename filters to filter out everything except directories (filter out all files). I manage to list just directories but when I download the parent directory to my computer there is no sub directories at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with FileZilla 3.12.0.2 and it doesn't seem to work. When downloading such a filtered list, simply nothing is downloaded. FileZilla does not create directories if there are no files to be downloaded. [This is a known bug.](http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/3836)